# How to convert the data type of a property in a DataContract on client side?

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

I have a WCF service which returns a `List<MyData>` object. `MyData` is a DataContract class with bunch of properties in it, one of which is `UnixTime` of type `Int64`. I want this in C# DateTime format. I know how to convert unix time to regular DateTime values. What I want to know is, is there a way that I can change my DataContract on the client side (or some other idea) where in I can convert the unix time to regular time format so that I can directly access the value from my `List<MyData>` object?

Edit:
I am not actually adding the service reference to my solution. I am calling the wcf service throught the `HttpWebRequest` object and deserializing the output response using the `JavaScriptSerializer`. I created my own classes for the data contract as the response object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Tim S for the helpful tip.

I created a new property called `MSDateTime` in my `MyData` class without the `[DataMember]` attribute and returned the converted value of my unixtime. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `DateTime` property to your `MyData` class:

```
public DateTime UnixDateTime
{
    get
    {
        return MyConversionMethod(this.UnixTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not actually adding the service reference to my solution. I am calling the wcf service throught the `HttpWebRequest` object and deserializing the output response using the `JavaScriptSerializer`. I created my own classes for the data contract as the response object. I am sorry for missing this detail in my actual question.

Comment: @PushCode I've updated my answer to be better suited to that scenario.

Comment: Thats what exactly I did :) and replied the same in the thread. Thank you though.